# Second drop down menu changing its value automatically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have 2 drop down menus, second drop down menu is populated based on first drop down menu, the problem is when press Tab or Submit button the value of second drop down menu is automatically changing it self or showing empty.

**Script:**

```
function ajaxfunction(parent) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.control').change(function() {
      var Value = $(this).val();
      if (Value != null) {
        jQuery.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: "name.php?comp_type=" + Value,
          success: function(data) {
            $('#name').html(data);
          }
        });
      }
    })
  })
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<!-- first dop down menu -->
<select name="type" class="control" onchange="ajaxfunction(this.value)">
  <option value="Electronice">Electroinc</option>
  <option value="Fashion">Fashion</option>
  <option value="Education">Electroinc</option>
</select>

<!-- second drop down menu -->
<select id="name" name="name"></select>
```

Sorry about my English

Comment: You are using `ajaxfunction()` onchange of select and also binding change event on it within that function. This is not correct

Comment: @anu I just modified my code, working fine thank you for commenting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the function when page is loaded

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
          ajaxfunction();
      });

 function ajaxfunction(parent){
       $('.control').change(function(){
        var Value = $(this).val();
        if(Value != null){
            jQuery.ajax({     
                type: 'POST',         
                url: "name.php?comp_type="+Value,             
                success: function(data){ 
                    $('#name').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    })

}
</script>
```

Comment: And also remove `onchange="ajaxfunction(this.value)` from the dom element

Answer (score 0):

Keep all as is just update your code as below

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.control').change(function() {
      var Value = $(".control").val();
      if (Value != null) {
        jQuery.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: "name.php?comp_type=" + Value,
          success: function(data) {
            $('#name').html(data);
          }
        });
      }
    })
  });
```

And html as below:

```
<!-- first dop down menu -->
<select name="type" class="control">
  <option value="Electronice">Electroinc</option>
  <option value="Fashion">Fashion</option>
  <option value="Education">Electroinc</option>
</select>

<!-- second drop down menu -->
<select id="name" name="name"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use another option to display dropdown services is below this way.You can use ajax throw display content.

1. Test.php

   ```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js">       </script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("select.country").change(function(){
           var selectedCountry = $(".country option:selected").val();
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "process-request.php",
               data: { country : selectedCountry } 
           }).done(function(data){
               $("#response").html(data);
           });
       });
   });
   </script>

   </head>
   <body>
   <form>
       <table>
           <tr>
               <td>
                   <label>Country:</label>
                       <select class="country">
                           <option>Select</option>
                           <option value="usa">United States</option>
                           <option value="india">India</option>
                           <option value="uk">United Kingdom</option>
                       </select>
               </td>
               <td id="response"></td>
           </tr>
       </table>
    </form>
    </body> 
    </html>
   ```
2. process-request.php

   ```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST["country"])){
      $country = $_POST["country"];
      $countryArr = array("usa" => array("New Yourk", "Los Angeles", "California"), "india" => array("Mumbai", "New Delhi", "Bangalore"),
               "uk" => array("London", "Manchester", "Liverpool"));
      if($country !== 'Select'){
      echo "<label>Services:</label>";
      echo "<select>";
       foreach($countryArr[$country] as $value){
         echo "<option>". $value . "</option>";
        }
         echo "</select>";
         } 
        }
      ?>
   ```